# Visio: Have shapesheet value on background, but show currentpage value

Tags: field, visio, shapesheet

Looking for a way to have a field on the background page, to change value when switching to other pages.

Example.
I have  a titlebox on the background page, and a user-defined field that shows ISO pagesize (A1, A2, Etc) with the following formula

```
="A"&4-LOG10(INT((ThePage!PageWidth*ThePage!PageHeight)/(POW(ThePage!DrawingScale/ThePage!PageScale,2)*62370 sq mm)))/LOG10(2)
```

This works fine on the background page, and shows the correct A1 for now.

But when i go to another page using that background page, and set this page to be A2, it still shows A1.

***This is not necessary for Drawing size. But it applies for drawing scale. I want this field to be in the background page, and reflect the correct scale for the actual page.***

Is this a possibility.

Comment: All pages in your document have same page size?

Comment: Not necessarily :)